# Как обновить (пересчитать значение) скроллбар в SPA-приложении

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Имеется SPA-приложение на Backbone+Marionette. При рендере в регион CollectionView с большим количеством элементов на странице появляется скроллбар. После того, как количество элементов коллекции меняется в меньшую сторону, то высота страницы уменьшается, но скроллбар остается таким же, образуя под страницей лишнее пустое место. Подскажите, как можно средствами нативного JS или JQuery заставить страницу пересчитать высоту и изменить скроллбар?

Comment: Скажем так, вопрос поставлен очень абстрактно, а потому сложно на него дать ответ. 

Здесь все надо смотреть, и шаблон айтема, и шаблон страницы, и CSS для всего этого.

У меня никогда не было таких проблем с коллекциями даже при больших размерах коллекций.
Попробуйте набросать пример на jsfiddle.net возможно получится проанализировать.

Comment: Это происходит в рамках довольно большого проекта, с использованием requireJS, потому импорт в JSFIddle займет немало времени, а на простом примере может и не проявиться. Я просто думал что может какие-либо решения по рефрешу скроллбара есть уже из коробки

Comment: Размер проекта не имеет значения. Мне кажется, вам надо уделить больше внимания верстке и стилям именно тех блоков, где происходит рендер коллекции. Так же проверьте в разных браузерах. Еще есть предположение, что вы устанавливаете высоту блока, но не сбрасываете при уменьшении.